# Linux gnu screen - run commands immediately when screen starts?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

In my .screenrc file, I have this line to open one screen window:

```
screen -t "normal"
```

And this line to open another window and run top:

```
screen -t "top" top
```

Those work just fine so I wanted to immediately run `df && ls -alh` in a third window, so I placed this line into the .screenrc:

```
screen -t "df" df && ls -alh
```

The df window never appears so I thought the && may be the cause of the problem and tried it with just df.

```
screen -t "df" df
```

The df window still fails to appear.

Question: How can I run one command followed by another in the same screen window via screenrc? I'd like for it to behave exactly as it does in bash. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably appears, but disappears after it ran.

Try the following:

```
screen -t "df" bash -c 'df && sleep 50'
```

This will show the output of the `df` command for `50` seconds.

To have a useful `df` output I would recommend you to use `watch`:

```
screen -t "df" watch -n 10 df
```

This will runs `df` in every 10 seconds, so you'll have the actual status of your free disk space on that terminal.

Comment: That works. How do you keep the window from going away once the commands execute?

Comment: @01100110 I've updated my answer

Comment: This works, but when you reconnect to the screen and stop the df loop by pressing ctrl-c, the screen terminates. Any way to start the screen so the screen stays live even if the program started within stops?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but appeared in search results before the answer I found cleanest [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47279/128704).

Some solutions that worked for me:

```
screen -t Files zsh -c 'ls -lahG; exec zsh'
```

In my .screenrc file, the 'exec zsh' opens another command prompt in a window within a region after the 'ls' command/process completes (similar to the behavior of manually typing a command in the shell in a window in GNU screen manually; I am assuming it is more efficient than running a 'sleep' command, but appreciate being corrected if I am wrong.

```
screen -t Files zsh -c 'vim .'
```

The above works for the specific case of using 'ls'.