# Linux 'screen' command - Start a screen and something to run in it at the same time?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, display

I'm a big fan of the linux program "screen" which allows me to 
start a screen within a SSH session which can stay alive after
I disconnect. [More info about screen here](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/)

Is there a way I can start a screen session from a command line that automatically starts another program (or .sh script) within that screen session?

I'd like to add this to my raspberry pi's boot sequence so that there's always a screen running automatically running some software, even if the pi is restarted, so that I can ssh into the pi at any time to see that software's output.

I have looked at [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/412866/linux-gnu-screen-run-commands-immediately-when-screen-starts), but this only helps partially.
It starts screen like this

```
screen -t "df" watch -n 10 df
```

and successfully starts the "df" command.

However when the program is done running, the screen closes and disappears.

I would like the screen to stay alive even if the program originally started is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Change the command to:

```
screen -t "df" bash -c 'watch -n 10 df; exec bash'
```

`bash -c` : Use *bash -c* to run multiple commands.

`exec bash` : After *df* command terminates, it will start a shell (bash) that won't exit until something external terminates it.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by running the commands in a shell which stays running after the command completes.

For instance, in *[Prevent GNU screen from terminating session once executed script ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends)*, the accepted answer does an

```
exec bash
```

after the command, to start a shell when the command completes.